# Using 'exec' in Oracle trigger code and failed

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

i tried to create a Oracle trigger, after the table is insert or update, touch a file in the Linux host.

so i create a shell script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus $oam <<EOF
spool /ocs/ocsrun/other/gx_working/select.txt;
@/ocs/ocsrun/other/gx_working/select.sql;
spool off;
exit;
EOF
touch  /export/home/oracle/shell/a.txt
```

and modify the permission:

```
chmod 777 test1.sh
```

then i use the sys login oracle and create a scheduler job like this:

```
SQL>  exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name=>'test1',job_type=>'EXECUTABLE',job_action=>'/export/home/oracle/shell/test1.sh');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

now i want to create a Oracle trigger and call this scheduler job like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_OAM_LOG
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON OCS_CHARGE_OFF_AUTOMATION
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name=>'test1');
END;
/
```

when i update this table ,error like:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: No such file or
directory
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at "OAM.MY_OAM_LOG", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OAM.MY_OAM_LOG'
```

i serach some docs like exapmle 27-5 from the admin guide:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#i1032197

is error the same,after i change my shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient
export ORACLE_SID=ocsdb
sqlplus $oam <<EOF
spool /ocs/ocsrun/other/gx_working/select.txt;
@/ocs/ocsrun/other/gx_working/select.sql;
spool off;
exit;
EOF
touch  /export/home/oracle/shell/a.txt
```

the shell able to run independently,how do i dual with it?plz

Comment: Aside: **Never** use `chmod 777`. Not ever. Not to test. Not temporarily. UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES. Setting those permissions allows untrusted users (like accounts authenticating inbound Internet connections) to have *write* access to files another account is *executing*. It is innately an utterly unacceptable security practice.

Comment: ...as for the immediate error, personally, I'd start by tracing what Oracle is actually doing in practice, ie. with [sysdig](https://sysdig.org/). Determining whether it's actually calling an `execv`-family syscall with `/export/home/oracle/shell/test1.sh` as an argument, and what the result of that syscall is, would go a long way towards understanding the problem.

Comment: (By the way, that script doesn't look right -- it has part of a heredoc fragment, but it doesn't ever include anything that *starts* your heredoc; there should be a line with `<<EOF` starting the section that the line containing only `EOF` ends).

Comment: yes,there should be a <<EOF,i have repasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the sqlplus command cannot be found, because when executing from the Oracle database, you're missing out all your environment settings. So set the necessary paths in the beginning of your script or enter the complete path to commands like sqlplus.